# GetCookie And SetCookie JS not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, setcookie

In a ASP .NET webforms project I need to pass a cookie form one form to another. The code in the first page where I set the cookie as below:

```
   function set_cookie(name, value) {
         document.cookie = name + '=' + value;
     }
```

The method work just fine and I can see the cookie is set.

In the second page, I try to read the cookie but the problem I can't read the value. The code in of reading value is as below

```
 var getCookie = function (c_name) {
        var name = c_name + "="
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should better start using https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Comment: I did importj Query Cookiee to my application, but still have the same problem.

Comment: It could be an issue with the path of the cookie. Different browsers react differently when domain is `localhost`. Detail us more about the exact path of 2 pages.

Comment: After setting the cookie at Page 1 check in Developer toolbar what is the path and other properties for the same.

Comment: You may write debugger; within the function you wish to debug and press F12 for chrome. More info https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: When calling the setCookie method on $(document).ready do I need to add the parameter? something like this: set_cookie("myCheck");

Comment: The thing is I'm passing the cookie from one ASP .net form to another, and that is why it does not work. any suggestions?

Comment: did you run it like this? getCookie('cookie_name_here');